# Calling function from v8 engine throws error

Tags: c++, v8

I am making an application that requires me to call a function within some Javascript code. The problem is, despite looking it up many times, I still get the same error.

> No matching function for call to 'v8::Object::Get(v8::Local<v8::Context>&, v8::MaybeLocal<v8::String>)'

I have looked up on several different posts and even the documentation, yet I can't even start to run the function.

```
Isolate::CreateParams create_params;
        create_params.array_buffer_allocator = ArrayBuffer::Allocator::NewDefaultAllocator();
        Isolate* isolate = Isolate::New(create_params);
        {
            Isolate::Scope isolate_scope(isolate);
            HandleScope handle_scope(isolate);

            Local<Context> context = Context::New(isolate);
            Context::Scope context_scope(context);
            std::string fileContent = f.getContents("./src/solutions/6t10.js");;

            Local<String> source = String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, cv.stringToChar(fileContent), NewStringType::kNormal).ToLocalChecked();

            Local<Script> script = Script::Compile(context, source).ToLocalChecked();
            MaybeLocal<Value> result = script->Run(context).ToLocalChecked();

            Handle<Object> global = context->Global();
            MaybeLocal<String> strValue = String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, cv.stringToChar("prob"+std::to_string(pi)));
            Local<Value> value = global->Get(context, strValue);
            Handle<Function> func = Handle<Function>::Cast(value);
            Handle<Value> args[1] = { global->Get(context, String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, ca)) };
            MaybeLocal<Value> js_result = func->Call(context, global, 1, args);

            v8::String::Utf8Value answer(isolate, js_result.ToLocalChecked());
            answers+=*answer;

        }
        isolate->Dispose();
        delete create_params.array_buffer_allocator;
```

If you can't find the problem I'll ask this, how can I turn a LocalString to LocalValue? Thank you :)

Comment: according to the doc the second parameter needs to be Local<Value> not MaybeLocal<Value>

Comment: @pm100 Local and MaybeLocal have no effect with each other, as MaybeLocal is only there because it might be local, and still works with each other

Comment: @pm100 I was wrong forgive me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(V8 developer here.) @pm100's comment is spot on: `Local` and `MaybeLocal` are not interchangeable, a function that needs the former can't deal with the latter.

The "Maybe" part of the name indicates that due to some error that may have happened (usually an exception), the value might be nonexistent. The required explicit conversion helps *you* to ensure that you don't forget to check for this. (Many years ago, V8's API didn't have this distinction, and it was an endless source of bugs in embedder code.)

> how can I turn a Local to Local?

I guess you mean "how can I turn a **MaybeLocal** into a Local?".

There are two options for different scenarios, and your code already contains an example for one of them:
`MaybeLocal::ToLocalChecked()` checks if a value is present, crashes the process if not, and returns a `Local` otherwise. This is, unsurprisingly, appropriate when you can guarantee that no exception happened, e.g. for string allocations.
`MaybeLocal::ToLocal(Local* ...)` is for cases where you *can't* guarantee that a value is present (i.e. no exception happened) and you *don't* want to crash the process. It checks whether a value is present, returns `false` if not (so you can gracefully handle that case), and populates the `Local` in the out-parameter otherwise (and returns `true`). This is typically used for any values returned from JavaScript. As a specific example in your code: `js_result.ToLocalChecked()` will crash the process if `func->Call` threw an exception.

Comment: I updated the question due to a typo lol. Thanks for the response ill try it when I get home

Comment: Bro you gotta be a brainy-ac or somethings, cause you got my code to work like a charm!